# Abs-Last line up to the belly button (Home)

Tags: workout

even my diet is good even if workout. I can't do the "last line" on my abs.I mean up to the belly button.I do much workouts -strenth etc.As a result I think I do something wrong.Which workouts at home are proper for this line?thanks a lot

Comment: How do you know you *have* a last line? The "lines" on abs are connective fascia, everyone is different. You may not even have a last line.

Comment: JohnP's point is valid, but assuming you do, seeing it will be almost entirely a matter of reducing your body fat - you'll need to get it down to around 10% - and very little to do with your exercise selection.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do have an ability to get that line ( not everyone does ), you need to cut weight, like bodybuilders do. This can potentially involve serious carb cutting, HIIT like workouts, and strategically placed "cheat meals".

Research some cutting programs and try to follow one of them that doesn't seem "too crazy". 
Note that, your strength will probably take a dive.

Comment: +1 for low body fat, like in the 3% - 6% range. Also, low body fat is not healthy. Your brain, for example, uses body fat. It isn't good to stay at low body fat for extended periods of time.

Comment: @jp2code, Totally agree. Bodybuilders get that low only for one event, and max 2-3 times a year. The rest of it - they are in a healthy range of fat.